Upgrade 22.04 to 24.04 hangs on installing hunspell_de_de
Upgrade 22.04 to 24.04 hangs on installing hunspell_de_de
Upgrade sent a Massage saying it Wants to move to snap. I click on OK and Upgrade hangs.
OK was the only option available. At this point the only Thing that works is the mouse/keypad. It is Not passable to enter anything at all.

This question is similar to: Fixing , /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell mount issue. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

is OK the only option offered? [edit] in to your question
